# Extract the href value with apostrophe in Java

Tags: href, jsoup

I am a new user to JSoup. I want to extract the `href` value from the html.

For example:

```
 String html = "<p>An <a href='http://exa'mple.com'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
 Element link = doc.select("a").first();
 String linkHref = link.attr("href");
```

I am getting the output as `"http://exa"` , but I need the output as `"http://exa'mple.com"` (the raw text in href). `link.outerHtml()` is providing some different text.

I can't alter the HTML. HTML is the user's input.

Comment: That's simply not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`String html = "<p>An <a href='http://exa%27mple.com'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";`

Comment: we cant change the html content.

Comment: then how about `String html = "<p>An <a href=\"http://exa'mple.com\"><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";`

Comment: its a sample html ... i ll get the content like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how this will be possible, given that the jsoup parser will be expecting a ' to close the href argument and that's exactly what it gets. I think your only option is to pre-parse the string provided by the user, but even that will be tricky, as you'll have to come up with a rule to distinguish between "correct" and "incorrect" quote marks.